# Is it a normal wish?

Tags: greetings

How would someone summarize the phrase below if a departing employee receive this from boss: "Best wishes in your future pursuits"

Comment: This is standard formal talk. Say Thank You, nod, and smile. It means nothing.

Comment: Did you look up *wish* in a dictionary? It's not the main definition, but it's there: "an expression of a desire for someone's success or good fortune".

Comment: Thanks for explaining but I want to know is it on bad side or good side? What if an employee thank his boss on email, and get a reply?

Comment: @Laurel I had a chance to read the meaning of phrase "Best of luck in your future endeavors" online. it rally made me confuse. I asked this because I live in a developing country and worked in a multi-cultural environment.

Comment: What has been left is this: The words also signal the end of communication. Thank you. You're great. We are done. No other words will follow from my side. The words themselves are positive, but the underlying meaning is up to you to decode. A suggestion to use them as a future reference would tell you the message is sincere and not just a formality.

Comment: Instead of asking "summarize", you want to know how someone would **react**, or how should this message be **interpreted**? Does it **require a reply**? Yosef Baskin explains well why no response is required. The question  title does you no favour either.

Comment: To be clear, does the "departing employee" refer to an employee who is leaving the company because they will no longer be working for that company? What exactly  is the  reason for leaving? Did they find new employment, or did they move to a different town, city etc.? In any case, it's a polite way to close a transaction, or work relationship,  the client (or employer) is merely thanking that person. There is no need to reply, if this were a telephone conversation the recipient could reply "Thanks, it was a pleasure doing business with you" or "Thanks, I enjoyed my time working for you."

Answer (score 1):

It's a completely neutral, standard phrase to use in this context. It means "I hope you do well in whatever you do in the future". So if anything it's positive, but it's so standard that you can consider it neutral.

Same thing with "Best of luck in your future endeavors", they're two ways of saying the same thing.

Comment: IMHO, it's actually on the "nicer" side of neutral.  Nobody is obligated to wish someone else success.  They could just say, "Goodbye".  If someone said that to me, I'd appreciate it as a kind thing to say.

Answer (score 0):

Well wish:

noun. An instance of wishing well to someone or something; an expression of this, a good wish.

well wish - definition of well wish in English | Oxford Dictionaries